# prepareforreuse method prevents tableview cell data loading error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The method below is invoked right before the `UITableView`'s reuseable cell is returned. Can I use `prepareForReuse` to remove the photo in a cell that has scrolled away?

That way, the corrected image can load in a given cell and prevent the wrong photo from loading if the user has scrolled up or down too fast.

Can anyone tell me if this is okay or whether it's redundant to use it? Is there any other way to do it? (I use sd_webimage to load the images for my tableview).

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForreuse() 
    mypostImage.image = nil 
}
```

Comment: Are you already dequeing the cell with an identifier. If so, if appears to be overkill and completely unnecessary. Additionally, it might have unintended side effects.

Comment: yes , i already deque the cell, but if user scroll down the cells down very fast, some cell is out of deque cells, shouldn't need to download the image which i thought it would be waste of bandwith if a cell is out of view is no longer need it.  i think i am wrong, i am a newbie, very confused and blur about this area. thanks for answering my question